# How do I transfer UVs between high and low poly meshes?

Tags: uv, workflow

So I created a low-poly object. Then I duplicated it and made it high-poly. Then I UV unwrapped the low poly one. How can I transfer UVs from the low poly to the high poly object? When I try to do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it does not work because of different amount of loops:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the details of how you "made it high-poly."  If you made it high poly with an unapplied multiresolution or subdivision modifier, ctrl-L will work.  If you made it high poly with those modifiers, but you applied them, then you can make a copy of your unwrapped low-poly, give it those modifiers, and then ctrl-L copy the UV maps from the duplicate to the high poly.

If you made it high poly in some other way, like with dynotopo sculpting, then the short answer is that there isn't a good, braindead way to do it.

One thing you can do is to try a data transfer modifier to copy UV, which is face-corner data.  You would probably want to use nearest corner and best matching normal; you need to hit the "generate data layers" button to generate the UV map layers onto which your LP's UV can be copied.

The problem is that, with dynotopo, your LP may have seams that run directly through the faces of your HP.  There's no right, automatic way to handle this.  You could data transfer, pin most of the verts, and then re-unwrap any bad faces around those pins, which is reasonable.

Another way to handle this is do it on a per-texel basis instead of a per-vertex basis.  You don't end up with a UV map per-se, but you end up with something almost as good.  Start by unwrapping your HP however you see fit (a smart project is probably a good idea), then create a material for your LP that emits UV coordinates.  Now you can bake low-to-high to get per-texel coordinates from your HP.  You can reference this by running your UV into that baked texture and reading the output as a UV vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the two objects, and link their UV maps.

1. Select the "target" object
2. Select the "source" object (this needs to be the active object)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>> "Transfer UV maps"

Comment: doesnt work  that way. They doest not have the same amount of loops

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your low poly textured and ready;

1. Duplicate the low poly mesh
2. Add sub division modifier. (This preserves the UVs)
3. Add shrinkwrap modifier and set the target to high poly model. (To apply all the details)

This way you can transfer all the details like Uvs, textures, poses, etc. to high poly mesh. It's a simple way but always works for me. All the best!